# Doing a factorial with only one while loop

Tags: java, math, factorial

I'm trying to find the factorial of 9 down to 0, only using one while loop, but my idea isn't outputting a value.

I figured out the way to do it using two while loops:

```
    int i;
    count = 9;
    while (count >= 0){
        value = count;
        i = count-1;
        while (i > 0){
            value = value * i;
            i--;
        }
        System.out.print(value + ", ");
    }
```

This worked but I've tried to change it to use only one while loop and got this:

```
    int i;
    for (count = 9; count < 0; count--){
        value = count;
        i = count-1;
        while (i > 0){
            value = value * i;
            i--;
        }
        System.out.print(value + ", ");
    }
```

I'm not completely sure if I'm using the for statement correctly but I think I am, or at least I think it should output something so I can debug it.

Could someone give me a hint in the right direction?

Comment: can u use a for-loop together with the while-loop ?

Comment: `for (count = 9; count < 0; count--)` means: start with `count` as `9`; loop as long as `count` is smaller than `0`; decrement `count` by one on each iteration. So you see, `count < 0` should be `count >= 0`.

Comment: You shouldn't need two loops (for OR while) to compute a factorial. Think about your algorithm some more.

Comment: Change to count > = 0 in the for condition

Comment: You have to change your condition of the For-Loop to >=0

Comment: @Defa1t: You also can add a exclusive AND-Logic to your Code to get only one condition in the while (condition1 && condition2)

Comment: initialise a variable to 362880 and then in a loop with i going from 9 to 0 print the variable and then divide by i.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you all the factorials from 9 down to 1 :

```
int i=1;
int value=1;
String res = "";
while (i <= 9){
  value = value * i;
  res = value + ((i>1)?",":"") + res;
  i++;
}
System.out.print(res);
```

Output :

```
362880,40320,5040,720,120,24,6,2,1
```

Perhaps it's cheating, since I'm calculating the factorials in ascending order from `1!` to `9!`, but I'm reversing the order of the output in order to get the required result.

Edit :

If you also want 0! to be printed, a small change can do the trick :

```
int i=1;
int value=1;
String res = "";
while (i <= 10){
  res = value + ((i>1)?",":"") + res;
  value = value * i;
  i++;
}
System.out.print(res);
```

Output :

```
362880,40320,5040,720,120,24,6,2,1,1
```

Comment: Thanks so far, is there any chance you could explain this line? `res = value + ((i>1)?",":"") + res;`

Comment: @Defa1t the strange part in the middle is just meant to avoid having an extra "," at the end of the output (it adds "," only if i>1). This line adds the next factorial ahead of the previously calculated factorials, so that the output would be reversed (starting with 9! and ending with 1!).

Answer (score 1):

Just first assign value=i, then run your loop. You can get the factorial with only while loop.

**Important:** Because `n!=n*(n-1)!`, therefore,  `i--` should must be perform before `value = value * i`.

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {

            int value=5;
            int i=value; 
                while (i > 1){

                    i--;
                    value = value * i;
                }
                System.out.print(value);

    }
```

Update: If you want to count factorial of 0 to 9, then use this code: (It includes factorial of 0 also)

```
  public static void main(String args[]){
        int countLowest=0; 
        int countHighest=9; 
        int value=1;


                while (countLowest<= countHighest){
                if(countLowest==0)
                    value = value * (countLowest+1);
                else
                    value=value*countLowest;
                countLowest++;
                System.out.println("Factorial of "+(countLowest-1)+" is "+value);
                }

    }
```

**Result:**

```
Factorial of 0 is 1
Factorial of 1 is 1
Factorial of 2 is 2
Factorial of 3 is 6
Factorial of 4 is 24
Factorial of 5 is 120
Factorial of 6 is 720
Factorial of 7 is 5040
Factorial of 8 is 40320
Factorial of 9 is 362880
```

Comment: I believe the idea was to get all the factorials from 9 to 0 with a single while loop. You only calculate a single factorial.

Comment: Sorry, I did not noticed it. In that case, the result should also show factorial of 0, I just updated my code.

Comment: If order is important, just storing results initially in an array and printing it in reverse way will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

First, the reason why your second loop doesn't work is that you have the wrong condition in the `for`. The condition in the middle is one that will cause the loop to **continue**, not to stop. So what you were saying was "start from 9, and work while the number is less than 0". But of course, your number is greater than zero to begin with.

Second, I believe using a `for` loop is a little bit of cheating, because a `for` loop is just a specific case of `while` loop.

Now to the problem of the factorial itself. You know that a factorial n! is defined as (n-1)!*n.

The basic loop for calculating one specific factorial is:

```
int n = 5;
int factorial = 1;

while ( n > 0 ) {
    factorial *= n;
    n--;
}

System.out.println( "Factorial is: " + factorial );
```

This will give you the factorial of five. But it's not exactly based on the formula we are talking about. There is another way to calculate it, starting from 1:

```
int n = 5;
int factorial = 1;
int count = 1;
while ( count <= n ) {
   factorial *= count;
   count++;
}
System.out.println( "Factorial is " + factorial );
```

The interesting part about this way of doing it is that in every stage of the loop, `factorial` is actually the value (count-1)! and we are multiplying it by count. This is exactly the formula we were talking about.

And the good thing about it is that just before you did it, you had the value of the previous factorial. So if you printed it then, there you'd get a list of all the factorials along the way. So here is a modified loop that prints all the factorials.

```
int n = 9;
int factorial = 1;
int count = 0;
while ( count < n ) {
   System.out.println( "Factorial of " + count + " is " + factorial );
   count++;
   factorial *= count;
}
System.out.println( "Factorial of " + n + " is " + factorial );
```

Note that I modified it a little more so that it will work with zero. The factorial of zero is a special case so we shouldn't multiply by zero - that will make all the factorials wrong. So I changed the loop to multiply only after I increase `count` to 1. But this also means that you have to print the final factorial out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
 count = 9;
sum=1;
while (count >= 1){
sum*=count;
--count;
 }
    System.out.print(sum);
```

it will give you 9!=362880